# Expand Recordset and Add DATEADD

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to pull records out of one table named 'TBL_FBNK_LIMIT_HIST_TRANS_SPLIT' and expand the number, based on the 'Frequency' field, update the DateIncrement, and load everything into a final table named 'TBL_FBNK_LIMIT_HIST_TRANS_SPLIT_FINAL'

Here is my DLL

```
DROP TABLE Reporting_Table
CREATE TABLE Reporting_Table (
    Credit_Line_NO      Varchar(255),
    Limit_Currency      Varchar(3),
    Amount              Decimal(16,6),
    Review_Frequency    Varchar(255),
    STARTDATE           Date,
    EXPIRYDATE          Date,
    FREQUENCY           INT,
    AsOfDate            Date)

INSERT INTO Reporting_Table (Credit_Line_NO, Limit_Currency, AMOUNT, Review_Frequency, STARTDATE, EXPIRYDATE, FREQUENCY, AsOfDate)
 Values('9938810','USD','16875.000000','20180331M0331','2017-12-31','2019-09-30','7','2017-11-30') 

INSERT INTO Reporting_Table (Credit_Line_NO, Limit_Currency, AMOUNT, Review_Frequency, STARTDATE, EXPIRYDATE, FREQUENCY, AsOfDate)
 Values('9938810','USD','16875.000000','20180331M0331','2017-12-31','2019-09-30','7','2017-11-30') 

INSERT INTO Reporting_Table (Credit_Line_NO, Limit_Currency, AMOUNT, Review_Frequency, STARTDATE, EXPIRYDATE, FREQUENCY, AsOfDate)
 Values('9938810','USD','16875.000000','20180331M0331','2017-12-31','2019-09-30','7','2017-11-30') 

INSERT INTO Reporting_Table (Credit_Line_NO, Limit_Currency, AMOUNT, Review_Frequency, STARTDATE, EXPIRYDATE, FREQUENCY, AsOfDate)
 Values('9938810','USD','16875.000000','20180331M0331','2017-12-31','2019-09-30','7','2017-11-30') 

INSERT INTO Reporting_Table (Credit_Line_NO, Limit_Currency, AMOUNT, Review_Frequency, STARTDATE, EXPIRYDATE, FREQUENCY, AsOfDate)
 Values('9938810','USD','16875.000000','20180331M0331','2017-12-31','2019-09-30','7','2017-11-30') 

INSERT INTO Reporting_Table (Credit_Line_NO, Limit_Currency, AMOUNT, Review_Frequency, STARTDATE, EXPIRYDATE, FREQUENCY, AsOfDate)
 Values('9938810','USD','16875.000000','20180331M0331','2017-12-31','2019-09-30','7','2017-11-30') 

INSERT INTO Reporting_Table (Credit_Line_NO, Limit_Currency, AMOUNT, Review_Frequency, STARTDATE, EXPIRYDATE, FREQUENCY, AsOfDate)
 Values('9938810','USD','16875.000000','20180331M0331','2017-12-31','2019-09-30','7','2017-11-30') 

Select * 
From Reporting_Table
```

The key here is that I know there are 7 quarters between 12/31/2017 and 9/30/2019, and I want to increment the DateIncrement by each quarter-end date, from 12/31/2017 to 9/30/2019.  How can I do that?  I came up with the script below, which should be pretty close, but it keeps telling me I have 'Incorrect syntax near ('  UGH!!!

I want the final DateIncrement to look like this.

[image]

It will reset for each Credit_Line_No and AsOfDate, so I think I need to Group By these two fields...I think...  I am using SQL Server 2008.

```
with cte as (
  select CREDIT_LINE_NO,LIMIT_CURRENCY,AMOUNT,REVIEW_FREQUENCY,STARTDATE,EXPIRYDATE,FREQUENCY,AsOfDate,EFFECTIVESTARTDATE, DateIncrement,
         1 as Rec_Iteration
  from TBL_FBNK_LIMIT_HIST_TRANS_SPLIT
  where FREQUENCY > 1
  union all  
  select CREDIT_LINE_NO,LIMIT_CURRENCY,AMOUNT,REVIEW_FREQUENCY,STARTDATE,EXPIRYDATE,FREQUENCY,AsOfDate,EFFECTIVESTARTDATE, DateIncrement,
        Rec_Iteration + 1
  from cte
  where Rec_Iteration < FREQUENCY
)
INSERT TBL_FBNK_LIMIT_HIST_TRANS_SPLIT_FINAL (CREDIT_LINE_NO,LIMIT_CURRENCY,AMOUNT,REVIEW_FREQUENCY,STARTDATE,EXPIRYDATE,FREQUENCY,AsOfDate,EFFECTIVESTARTDATE, DATEADD(qq,1,STARTDATE) as DateIncrement)
Select CREDIT_LINE_NO,LIMIT_CURRENCY,AMOUNT,REVIEW_FREQUENCY,STARTDATE,EXPIRYDATE,FREQUENCY,AsOfDate,EFFECTIVESTARTDATE, DateIncrement
From cte
```

Comment: well your syntax problem is that you have `DATEADD(qq,1,STARTDATE) as DateIncrement` in your column list .. `INSERT INTO TBL_FBNK_LIMIT_HIST_TRANS_SPLIT_FINAL (..., DATEADD(qq,1,STARTDATE) as DateIncrement)`.. it should just be `DateIncrement` and the dateadd function in the select portion

Comment: AH YES!!  I see what's happening now.  The DateIncrement is 1 quarter ahead of the StartDate, which is great, to start.  However, I want the DataIncrement to increment itself, like I showed in the yellow field in the image.  It seems like it would require another CTE, with a Row_Counter, or something like that.

Comment: if you just need the dateincrement value you can just select `dateadd(quarter, row_number() over (partition by Credit_Line_No, AsOfDate order by Credit_Line_NO), STARTDATE)`

Comment: YES, YES, YES!! !  That's it.  I should have known that......  Oh well, you learn something new every day.